# jQueryMobile - JSON Request

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am struggling to get my $.getJSON to initiate in jQuery mobile. I have tried calling it after jQuery is loaded and before jQueryMobile to no avail. I have also tried different functions at the start like:

```
$(document).ready
$(document).bind("mobileinit"
```

etc.

Here is what I have. The first alert runs, but it seems to stop when it reaches the JSON section.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){

    $('#home_screen').live('pagecreate',function(event) {

        alert('Loaded'); // Runs fine

        $.getJSON('includes/data/get.php',{'request_type':'count'}, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                alert(2);
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: What does firebug say? Any errors? Can you try the path as an absolute path? `/includes/data/get.php`

Comment: It runs perfectly in Firefox. It's when I load it up on my iPhone it doesn't do it. I added another alert after the JSON stuff, it appears to be skipping the JSON part completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.ajax (and then jQuery.parseJSON) instead of $.getJSON so you can actually debug what's going on by setting the error callback.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tried changing it to $.ajax but it still isn't doing anything. Any suggestions on what to do next? You would think something like this would be easy on jQueryMobile.

Comment: Have you tried setting your path relative to the root folder? "/relative/to/the/root/folder" instead of 'relative/to/current/folder'